# EF6 entity model suggestion

Tags: entity-framework

I have 2 tables Person and Student. Person has a 1-to-1 relationship with Student. The fields are:

```
Person
  - ID
  - FirstName
  - LastName

Student
  - PersonID
```

I also have 2 classes:

```
public class Person
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public int LastName { get; set; }
}

public class Student : Person
{
}
```

I now need to create DbSets for them so I can access the tables. My question is, is it OK to create one DbSet for the Student (which would need splitting) or should I just create 2 DbSets. One for Person one for Student?

Comment: Your model account not a standart 1-to-1 relationship, but inheritance instead, which makes person to inline its fields to Student table. Is it what you really want?

Comment: If you want to create relationship one-to-one you should to create two independent tables without inheritance. But as this tables are very similar, for their cooperative processing and to not depend on specific type, you can implement one common interface for each of them.